# How do we convert a direction vector to an angle?

Tags: java, math

If I have  a vector `v1(-4,3)` where it starts from `v0(0,0)`. How do I find out the direction in said, in *angle* or *radian* representation ?. The *magnitude* of the vector is `sqrt((-4-0)^2 + (3-0)^2)` which is `5`. If the direction is `(|-4/5|, |3/5| )` which is `(0.8, 0.6)` then how do I convert this in an angle representation? Will this be clockwise, counter-clockwise?

Comment: Use `Math.atan2`. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-) for how to use it and interpret the result.

Comment: The slope is rise over run or delta-y/delta-x.  That value is the tangent of the one of the acute angles of the right triangle (it depends on how you you orient it).  The degree of that angle is the arctan of the slope.  As @AndyTurner specified.

Comment: do we directly insert this (0.8, 0.6) to the `atan`? Do we need to somehow scale the coordinate?

Comment: As long as the ratio is the same and the values are double (not integer) it won't matter (within reason that is, there is a limit due to double precision.  But that is a programming language thing not a math thing). Think similar triangles.  Now drawing the vector is another thing entirely.

Comment: Also be mindful whether the result is expressed in degrees or radians.

Comment: @WJS, I see, so you mean `atan2(3/-4)` = `atan2(0.6 /- 0.8)` ?. EDIT : of course.lol

Comment: No, atan2 takes two arguments.  In your case it'll be double radians = Math.atan2(3, -4);  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-math-atan2-java/

Comment: @duffymo, I mean not literally in a java function. But, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to answer this question is to experiment:

```
public class TangentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = -4.0;
        double y = 3.0;
        double radians = Math.atan2(y, x);
        System.out.println(String.format("Angle: %10.6f radians %10.6f degrees", radians, Math.toDegrees(radians)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes and `double radians = Math.atan2(0.6, -0.8);` produces the same result. I prefer this because it's normalized.

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone : You do not gain anything by the normalization, as it is also done internally in the atan2 function. You only change the location where the corresponding rounding error occurs.

Comment: Normalization makes no difference.  A rudimentary understanding of vectors tell you why: the angle that a vector makes in the plane is no different from that of its unit vector.  No need to normalize - it's a waste of cycles with no benefit.

Comment: Woah. I didn't know that atan normalizes it internally.  Thanks again.